# Why native query is not working in following second query?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In between the two methods, the first method is written down with JPQL and the second method is in native query.

```
 1.   @Query("select e from Meeting  e where e.meetingName like %:query%" )
    List<Meeting> findByJPQL(@Param("query") String query);

 2.  @Query( nativeQuery = true, value ="select * from meeting as m where m.meeting_name like '%':query'%'" )
    List<Meeting> findByNativeQuery(@Param("query") String query);
```

The number one has given proper value but number two doesn't, can anybody tell us what is a problem in the second query?

Comment: Because you are escaping the %.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to escape the `:query` parameter at all. This is kind-of documented in the docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.advanced-like

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value ="select * from meeting as m where m.meeting_name like %:query%" )
List<Meeting> findByNativeQuery(@Param("query") String query);
```

The parameter binding for native queries uses similar code that is used for binding JPQL queries.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/dccc58040b2eb59f1ed425df491e6de87b130897/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/StringQuery.java#L232

which returns a `static class LikeParameterBinding extends ParameterBinding` from:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/StringQuery.java#L288